# how to append the written data to a file?

Tags: java, android, file-io, append

i am new developer in android.i would like to write some content to a file i have used a method to write into a file as follows

```
 public void writeFile(String path,String text){
    try{
    Writer output = null;
    File file = new File(path);
      output = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));
      output.write(text);
      output.close();
      System.out.println("Your file has been written");  
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

here i am passing path of a file and text to write.if i use in this way i can write the data but the previous data is losing.

how can i append or insert the latest text into a file without losing previous text?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this. Change this line ...

```
output = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));
```

to

```
output = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file, true));
```

The true indicates that you want to append not overwrite

Answer (score 3):

Have a look [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/FileWriter.html#FileWriter%28java.io.File,%20boolean%29) and try:

```
new FileWriter(file, true);
```

the boolean indicates whether or not to append to an existing file.